# Teamcity ant build classpath - how to add additional jars

Tags: ant, jar, teamcity

In Teamcity I'm kicking off an Ant Build. I want to add additional jars to the classpath, including ant-javamail.jar

How do I specify these in the settings control panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you specify "-lib /path/to/ant-javamail.jar" in the "Additional Ant command line parameters:" of your Ant Runner's configuration in TC?

References:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Ant